# White Space Removal At the end of a line C++

Tags: c++, c++11

The code is supposed to multiply two matrices and print the output. It works fine except for it prints an extra space at the end of each line, and the online submission service wont accept it with that space. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
void matrixMultiply(int A[][10],int m,int n,int B[][10],int p,int q)
{
    int sum=0;
    int **product ;
    product = new int*[m];
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
        product[i] = new int[q];

    if(n!=p)
    {
        cout<<"The two matrices have incompatible dimensions."<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"The product is:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<p;k++)
            {
                sum+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
            }
            product[i][j]=sum;
            sum=0;
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
            cout<<product[i][j]<<" "; //This is where the problem is
            cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int m=0,n=0;
    int p=0,q=0;

    int A[10][10];
    int B[10][10];

    string val1, val2;

    string m1=" ",m2=" ";
    string choice = "y";
    cout<<"Enter first matrix:"<<endl;
    do
    {
        getline(cin, m1);
        if(m1.compare("")==0)
            break;
        stringstream ss(m1);
        n=0;
        while(ss>>val1)
        {
            A[m][n]=stoi(val1);
            n++;
        }
        m++;

    }while(cin.peek());
    cout<<"Enter second matrix:"<<endl;
    do
    {
        getline(cin, m2);
        if(m2.compare("")==0)
            break;
        stringstream ss(m2);
        q = 0;
        while(ss>>val2)
        {
            B[p][q]=stoi(val2);
            q++;
        }
        p++;

    }while(cin.peek());


    matrixMultiply(A,m,n,B,p,q);

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample**

```
Enter first matrix:
1 2 3
4 5 6

Enter second matrix:
7 8
9 0
1 2

The product is:
28 14 <- extra space
79 44 <- extra space
```

Comment: You want to print the space after every element *except the last one in a row*. This would be when `j == q-1`. Alternatively, print the space *before* every element, except the first one. This may break if either dimension of the matrix is 1, though. Does that give you an idea? :)

Comment: Yeah the problem is that it has to work with matrices that are 1 dimensional as well.

Comment: What I'm saying is you'll have to handle that as well. For example... when `q > 1` and `j < q-1`, it should be safe to print your space

Comment: As a side-note, once you fix the spacing issue, you should probably post this to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I know i just cant figure out where to put that to make it still print the entire matrix. Would you recommend using a while loop?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let's add some missing braces, since the `endl` clearly isn't associated with the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
    {
        cout << product[i][j] << " "; //This is where the problem is
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Good habit to get into. In any event, if the problem is the trailing space just change your logic around. Instead of always printing a space after every element - print one *before* every element, so the inner loop becomes:

```
for (int j=0; j<q; ++j) {
    cout << ' ' << product[i][j];
}
```

And now we just have to deal with the extra leading space... which is easy, don't print a space on the first element:

```
for (int j=0; j<q; ++j) {
    if (j) {
        cout << ' ';
    }
    cout << product[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried to print the space in the front but I hadn't thought to use the if statement. Can you explain a little more how just if (j) will prevent the space from being printed before the first element?

Comment: @GrahamFoster Well, what does `if (j)` do, and at what points in the loop will that be true?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what if (j) does since there is nothing being compared with it

Comment: If evaluates the content, if it is true it executes the code. So if(0) on the first iteration is false, thus the code in the braces is not executed. Any value bigger than 0 is true, 0 is false